# Display <div> if a specific <td> exist on page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a web page that contains following HTML elements.

```
<div class="warning">Your payment is pending.</div>

<td class="pending">Payment Pending</td>
```

I want to display `div.warning` Only if the `td.pending` exists.

Is there a non-jQuery way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean to say: only if td.pending follows div.warning?

Comment: If you're asking if there is a CSS-only way of achieving this - then no. But if you are simply opposed to jQuery and are okay with clean JavaScript instead then hev1's answer will work for you. There is a CSS solution that __might__ be applicable if one can assume that the parent container of those two divs will only ever contain one or both of those divs though.

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `document.querySelector` for this purpose.

```js
const pending = document.querySelector('td.pending');
if(pending != null){
  document.querySelector('div.warning').style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.warning {
  display: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<div class="warning">Your payment is pending.</div>

<td class="pending">Payment Pending</td>
</tr>
</table>
```